# Correct way to save nested formsets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a 3-level Test model I want to present as nested formsets.  Each Test has multiple Results, and each Result can have multiple Lines.  I am following [Yergler's method](http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/) for creating nested formsets, along with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832672/django-inline-formsets-with-a-complex-model-for-the-nested-form) that updates Yergler's code for more recent Django version (I'm on 1.4)

I am running into trouble because I want to use FormSet's "extra" parameter to include an extra Line in the formset.  The ForeignKey for each Line must point to the Result that the Line belongs to, but cannot be changed by the user, so I use a HiddenInput field to contain the Result in each of the FormSet's Lines.

This leads to "missing required field" validation errors because the `result` field is always filled out (in add_fields), but the `text` and `severity` may not (if the user chose not to enter another line).  I do not know the correct way to handle this situation.  I *think* that I don't need to include the initial `result` value in add_fields, and that there must be a better way that actually works.

**Update below towards bottom of this question**

I will gladly add more detail if necessary.

The code of my custom formset:

```
LineFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Line,  
    form=LineForm,
    formset=BaseLineFormSet,
    extra=1)

class BaseResultFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseResultFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        result = super(BaseResultFormSet, self).is_valid()

        for form in self.forms:
            if hasattr(form, 'nested'):
                for n in form.nested:
                    n.data = form.data
                    if form.is_bound:
                        n.is_bound = True  
                    for nform in n:
                        nform.data = form.data
                        if form.is_bound:
                            nform.is_bound = True
                    # make sure each nested formset is valid as well
                    result = result and n.is_valid()
        return result

    def save_all(self, commit=True):
        objects = self.save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            for o in objects:
                o.save()

        if not commit:
            self.save_m2m()

        for form in set(self.initial_forms + self.saved_forms):
            for nested in form.nested:
                nested.save(commit=commit)

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        # Call super's first
        super(BaseResultFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)

        try:
            instance = self.get_queryset()[index]
            pk_value = instance.pk
        except IndexError:
            instance=None
            pk_value = hash(form.prefix)


        q = Line.objects.filter(result=pk_value)
        form.nested = [
            LineFormSet(
                queryset = q, #data=self.data, instance = instance, prefix = 'LINES_%s' % pk_value)]
                prefix = 'lines-%s' % pk_value,
                initial = [
                    {'result': instance,}
                ]
            )]
```

Test Model

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)

    attempt = models.ForeignKey(Attempt, blank=False, null=False)
    alarm = models.ForeignKey(Alarm, blank=False, null=False)

    trigger = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tested = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=True)
```

Result Model

```
class Result(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)   
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)

    location = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=locations)
    was_audible = models.CharField('Audible?', max_length=8, choices=audible, default=None, blank=True)
```

Line Model

```
class Line(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result, blank=False, null=False)

    text = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=severities, default=None)
```

---

**Update**

Last night I added this to my LineForm(ModelForm) class:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    saved_instance = None

    if not(len(self.changed_data) == 1 and 'result' in self.changed_data):
            saved_instance = super(LineForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    return saved_instance
```

It ignores the requests to save if *only* the result (a HiddenInput) is filled out.  I haven't run into any problems with this approach yet, but I haven't tried adding new forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used `extra` on formsets in similar situation I ended up having to include all the required fields from the model in the form, as HiddenInputs. A bit ugly but it worked, curious if anyone has a hack-around.

**edit**
I was confused when I wrote above, I'd just been working on formsets using `extra` with `initial` to pre-fill the extra forms and also I hadn't fully got all the details of your questions.

If I understand correctly, where you instantiate the `LineFormSet`s in `add_fields` each of those will point to the same `Result` instance?

In this case you don't really want to supply `result` in `initial` due to the problems you're having. Instead you could remove that field from the LineForm model-form altogether and customise the `LineFormSet` class something like:

```
class LineFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):
    # whatever other code you have in it already
    # ...
    # ...
    def __init__(self, result, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.result = result

    def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.result = self.result
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    def save_existing(self, form, instance, commit=True):
        return self.save_new(form, commit)
```

(this should be ok in Django 1.3 and 1.4, not sure other versions)

so the relevant part of your `add_fields` method would look like:

```
   form.nested = [
        LineFormSet(
            result = instance,
            queryset = q, #data=self.data, instance = instance, prefix = 'LINES_%s' % pk_value)]
            prefix = 'lines-%s' % pk_value,
        )]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how that works?  I'm already including one required field as a HiddenInput, which is the source of my problems (this being my first Django project doesn't help either)

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully enough, it just reminded me of something I'd been doing in my own code. I've revised my answer with something hopefully more helpful.

Comment: That makes sense from a Django-perspective, but by removing the ``result`` field from the model code would mean that Django would no longer save the result into the correct table anymore.  I think.  Being new to Django I'm not quite sure.

Comment: not from the model itself... from the ModelForm class, seems like you must have something like a `LineForm` class somewhere? Then to get the `result` saved into the model instances I have overridden the save methods of the ModelFormSet

Comment: Ah, I understand.  That makes a lot more sense to me now.  You are correct that I have a customized ``LineForm`` class.  I will rewrite the code in question, and come back to accept the answer.

Comment: Anentropic, I implemented this solution and found that all 'result' values show up for all 'test' values. Thus, the instance is not used to limit results values for each test instance. I am wondering if you have an answer for this? I posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523514/instance-not-being-used-in-nested-inlines